# Unity UI Text Doesn't Update

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have two buttons, one for Item1 and one for Item2, but Item2's text does update, but item1's not..

```
    using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ItemScript : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Image icon;
public string ItemName;
public UnityEngine.UI.Text ItemNameInfo;
public UnityEngine.UI.Text Item1countInfo;
public UnityEngine.UI.Text Item1costInfo;
public UnityEngine.UI.Text Item2countInfo;
public UnityEngine.UI.Text Item2costInfo;

public Click Click;
public float Item1cost = 100;
public float Item2cost = 500;
public int Item1count;
public int Item2count;
public static int itemMPS;
private float Item1basecost;
private float Item2basecost;

public Button Button;

void Start()
{
    Item1basecost = Item1cost;
    Item2basecost = Item2cost;
}

void Update()
{
    Item1countInfo.text = Item1count + "";
    Item2countInfo.text = Item2count + "";
    Item1costInfo.text = "Cost: " + Mathf.Round(Item1cost);
    Item2costInfo.text = "Cost: " + Mathf.Round(Item2cost);
}
public void Item1()
{
    if(Click.money >= Item1cost)
    {
        Click.money -= Item1cost;
        Click.money = Mathf.Round(Click.money * 10) / 10;
        itemMPS += 1;
        Item1count += 1;
        Item1cost = Item1basecost * Mathf.Pow(1.3f, Item1count);
        Item1cost = Mathf.Round(Item1cost);
    }
}

public void Item2()
{
    if (Click.money >= Item2cost)
    {
        Click.money -= Item2cost;
        Click.money = Mathf.Round(Click.money * 10) / 10;
        itemMPS += 2;
        Item2count += 1;
        Item2cost = Item2basecost * Mathf.Pow(1.3f, Item2count);
        Item2cost = Mathf.Round(Item2cost);
    }
}
```

}

As you see in above i have 2 Onclick event, but only the Item2 updates its text and Item 1 doesnt..

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough information here to answer your question. Can you post more of your UI code as well as the whole Update function?

Comment: See some more above, the code works, i tested it with debug, they are fine, but i dont know why the Item 1 text doesnt update and only Item 2 does, if i add one more item ex: item3 then only will item3's text will update

Comment: You need to post more code. E.g. what is ItemXcost and where do you declare them? And how? You may overwrite some declaration, or pass over the field to an event listener (as a reference, so the last one will be live only), or something like that. So basically, you did not post the code where you make the actual mistake. [OFF: these functions of yours are also low quality code, could be ways better by knowing what exactly are you trying to do]

Comment: Posted the full script above. Item1cost is the cost for item1, and item2 is the cost for item2, i dont want to merge them together, because if its like this then it's easier for me to save..